# Alter a table to add a foreign key constraint with a default value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How do I alter a table to have a column a foreign key constraint with a default value?

Comment: foreign key with default value ?? Sounds very odd to me

Comment: Perhaps explain why you think you need this, as it sounds like it could be an X/Y question.

Comment: @underscore_d: Perhaps not. I recently had this in a few tables where the default was to an "Unknown" element, to enable use of an indexed view (as indexed views cannot contain OUTER JOINs). Once the appropriate correct value was known, an UPDATE was performed. The context was a data scrubbing process where the FK value might be coming from any of several different "systems of record".

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The point is exactly that: "**Perhaps** not." If the OP explained the use case, we could confidently make a recommendation that we knew was really useful to them, rather than just literally answering their question but potentially encouraging a bad design.

Comment: @underscore_d: I have a regions table and Employee table. I need to update the employees table to have a column regionID with default value as 'US'

Comment: In my opinion such a default value for such a case should be done by the client. Forcing this in the database will stop the user from adding employees when there is no 'US' region

Answer (score 1):

In `T-SQL` if you're using `SQL-Server`, just be careful to put a real key for default. 
**Edit:** As said in the comments, be careful that you really need a default value for a foreign key, there could be a design problem.

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_columnname_default]
DEFAULT [your_default_value] FOR [columnname];  
GO  

ALTER TABLE [tablename]    
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_nameForeignKey] FOREIGN KEY (columnname)     
    REFERENCES [dbo].[oTable] (oTableID)      
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;    
GO
```

Comment: I would never ever advice to use cascade delete

Comment: "Never" is debatable, but i agree that in most case it's not useful, i'll edit my answer, but the OP already answered to his own question

Answer (score 0):

Well I did the following and it worked for me:

```
ALTER TABLE Employee
ADD RegionID varchar(3)
CONSTRAINT [Default_Value_Region] default ('US') NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [FK_EMPLOYEE_Region] FOREIGN KEY([RegionID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Region] ([Code])
GO
```

Comment: That's a default value for the **column** not for the foreign key constraint

Comment: Is Code the primary key in table Region ? If this field is editable than you will be in big problems when someone changes it

Comment: @GuidoG yes code is the primary key in the region table. And the field is more of hardcoded on as the value come from a drop down.